# Selenium:Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, iis

I have a web api application. Some method of the application runs chromedriver and makes some actions (sucs as clicks and taking screenshots)

Under Visual Studio application works well.
But when I publish my application to IIS, application throw Exception

> Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:51149 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

How to fix it?

I saw familar questions on StackOverflow, but I didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue because driver .quit was in side a method that executed before last method call. Fixed by removing the driver.quit from the existing page object method and put at the end of test method. Started working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I had many Chrome processes in task Manager. When I killed them, the application ran